# Mongoid creating embedded document from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to add a embed a Profile into a User and I keep getting this error.

```
   Access to the collection for Profile is not allowed since it is an embedded document, please access a collection from the root document.
```

I am sure it's a simple problem to fix but I have no clue how to do it. I am very new with RoR so things are still a little confusing.  Here is my code.

Models/Profile

```
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  attr_accessible :handle, :description

  field :handle
  field :description
  embedded_in :user
end
```

Controllers/Profile

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.profile.create!(params[:profile])
    redirect_to dashboard_path
  end
end
```

Views/profile/new

```
<h1>Create Profile</h1>

<%= form_for [:current_user, Profile.create] do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :handle %>
    <%= f.text_field :handle %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area:description %>
</div>

  <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Profile.create` in your `views.html.erb` because `Profile` is embedded in a user. So you need to do something like `current_user.build_profile`

```
<%= form_for [:current_user, current_user.build_profile] do |f| %>
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@user = current_user
@profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
@user.profile = @profile
@user.save
# or @profile.save
```

Comment: Yeah. Do you want me to post it?

Comment: Yes, please, add User model to the post

Comment: Oh, and version of MongoID. It can be a bug in old release.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/9442eecd12389670a525) to the code. Also I am using MongoID 2.0.1. Im sure its just something I am doing wrong though.